# ALT + Key is not working in Java 5 swing after an internal frame is closed

Tags: java, swing, alt, mnemonics

We migrated our swing application from JAVA 1.4 to JAVA 5, the problem we are facing is that the ALT + Key is not working in Java 5 after an internal frame is closed. It works as long as any of the internal frames are not closed.
It again works when it is minimized and maximized.

What I understand is, it is not getting the focus back to the Menu bar or it is not repainting the Menu properly which causes the ALT+key not to work.

Is there any specific reason for an already working code behaving like this, is this anyway related to the deprecated method setNextFocusableComponent which I don't think so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have a demonstrable example of your problem?

Comment: No, all I have is the existing code base which is huge.

Comment: Okay, will create one

Comment: cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/627387/GUI/java/ALT-Key-working-Java-internal

Comment: Just FYI, any internalframe that has TSSOptionPane while closing it allows the ALT+ key work normally and also for any other screens that extend from JDialog the ALT+key is working, any ideas why?

Comment: Got the solution, The InternalFrame close method was calling setClosed(true); which was taking the focus away from the menu after closing that frame. I replaced it with setVisible(false) and it started working